# Android O power state implicit broadcasts alternative

Tags: android

Since Android O imposes restrictions on implicit broadcasts, the following no longer works:

```
<receiver android:name=".model.PowerStateBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I considered registering for the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE` intent, launch a service and registering the listener for `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` in java from there, but the service would probably be killed.
I also considered using the `JobScheduler` with `setRequiresCharging(true)`, but according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#setRequiresCharging(boolean)):

> For purposes of running jobs, a battery-powered device "charging" is not quite the same as simply being connected to power. If the device is so busy that the battery is draining despite a power connection, jobs with this constraint will not run. This can happen during some common use cases such as video chat, particularly if the device is plugged in to USB rather than to wall power.

For an app whose behavior depends on knowing when the charger gets connected (its a battery/charging app), what would be the best approach to do this behavior now?

Comment: Use a foreground service.

Comment: @CommonsWare That would solve it, but users won't be happy. I already have a foreground service when the device is charging (that's when the app does stuff), but don't like having the notification 24/7.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other option, if you need real-time reactions. You could schedule a `JobScheduler` job that has a criteria of needing to be on a charger, but there is no guarantee that the job will run *immediately* upon being connected to a charger.